# Ubuntu is hung at the greeter

Tags: boot, unity-greeter

I have had a functional Ubuntu 18.04 system with Unity and unity-greeter installed. Now, after a while, it started hanging at unity-greeter: the greeter is displayed fine, but the computer doesn't react to keyboard nor mouse and I cannot switch to alternate terminals with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> etc.

The clock on the greeter screen is ticking.

I am able to boot to GRUB and choose alternate kernels to boot into, with or without recovery mode, but it hangs all the same.

The system is configured with LVM and full disk encryption. I am able to enter encryption password at the prompt, then hit Esc key to see diagnostic messages scrolling by, then the system is hung at the greeter.

**Where do I look to figure out what's wrong?** I suspect it's something video drivers or X-related, because I switched to the latest video drivers, X and stuff in order to optimize my gaming performance. I was going to switch from PlayOnLinux to Lutris, and started by installing the recommended drivers, latest Wine, then switching to the LTS Enablement Stack (just in case) and whatnot (I intended to document the changes, but haven't gotten around to it).

Comment: It sounds like you might already know the source of your issue since you made changes to your system, and then it stopped working.  To narrow down the culprit, revert the changes you made one by one, so that you can use process of elimination to rule out things and narrow your focus.

Comment: @Nmath For this, I need a way to boot into working system.

Comment: Can you at least get to a root prompt when you boot into recovery (with networking)?  Your problems seem to be with the desktop, so hopefully you should be able to get to a terminal if you don't load the desktop

Comment: @Nmath Yes, I am able to boot into recovery root prompt with networking. Is there a log I can read to figure out which system component causes the hang?

Comment: Try `dmesg|less` or look for log files via `find /var -name "*.log" | more` and inspect those that might be relevant. (As standard user you'd need `sudo` but not at recovery root prompt.)